# draw a line on movement of slider

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I am drawing an arc on slider movement. If you move slider arc will be drawn. Besided arc with canvas id canvasTwo I have drawn a line. I am trying to draw this line on movement of slider. So as slider moves line will be drawn. Which is currently happening only for arc. Any help. Please

```
            <!doctype html>
            <html lang="en">
                <head>
                    <meta charset="UTF-8">
                    <title>CH5EX10: Moving In A Simple Geometric Spiral </title>

                    <style>
                        .wrapper {
                            margin: 0 auto;
                            width: 1000px;
                        }
                        .uppleft {
                            float: left;
                            width: 1000px;
                            position: relative;
                            margin: 0 0 500px 10px;
                        }
                        .dnleft {
                            float: left;
                            width: 1000px;
                        }
                        .clear {
                            clear: both;
                        }
                    </style>

                </head>
                <body>
                    <div class="wrapper">
                        <div class="uppleft">

                            <canvas id="canvasOne" width="300" height="300"width="500" height="500" style="position:absolute; left:5px; top:10px; border:1px solid red;">
                                Your browser does not support HTML5 Canvas.
                            </canvas>
                            <canvas id="canvasTwo" width="300" height="300" style="position:absolute; left:250px; top:30px; border:1px solid red;">
                                Your browser does not support HTML5 Canvas.
                            </canvas>
                        </div>

                        <div class="clear"></div>

                        <div class="dnleft">
                            <input id="slide1" type="range" min="0" max="100" step="1" value="0" onchange="counterSliderNew('slide1', '100');" />
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </body>
                <script type="text/javascript">

                drawSlopeCurve1('canvasTwo')
                    function counterSliderNew(sID, maxValue) {

                        var slideVal = document.getElementById(sID).value;
                        //alert(slideVal);
                        if (maxValue == 100) {

                            slideVal = slideVal / 100;
                        }
                        var position = slideVal;
                        var startPt = {
                            x : 18.8,
                            y : 45
                        };
                        var controlPt = {
                            x : 28,
                            y : 160
                        };
                        var endPt = {
                            x : 228,
                            y : 165
                        };
                        if (slideVal == 0) {

                        } else if (slideVal > 0 && slideVal <= 34) {
                            erase('canvasOne');
                            drawBezier2('canvasOne', new Array({
                                x : 18.8,
                                y : 75
                            }, {
                                x : 28,
                                y : 160
                            }, {
                                x : 228,
                                y : 165
                            }), slideVal);

                        } else if (slideVal > 34 && slideVal <= 67) {
                            //alert(slideVal);
                            erase('canvasOne');
                            drawBezier2('canvasOne', new Array({
                                x : 18.8,
                                y : 75
                            }, {
                                x : 28,
                                y : 160
                            }, {
                                x : 228,
                                y : 165
                            }), slideVal);

                        } else if (slideVal > 67 && slideVal <= 100) {
                            erase('canvasOne');
                            drawBezier4('canvasOne', new Array({
                                x : 16,
                                y : 170
                            }, {
                                x : 160,
                                y : 72
                            }), slideVal);
                            //drawBezier3('canvasTwo', startPt, controlPt, endPt, position);

                        }
                    }

                    function drawBezier2(canId, points, slideVal) {

                        var canvas = document.getElementById(canId);

                        var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
                        // Draw guides
                        context.lineWidth = 2;
                        context.strokeStyle = "rgb(113, 113, 213)";
                        context.beginPath();
                        // Label end points
                        context.fillStyle = "rgb(0, 0, 0)";
                        // Draw spline segemnts
                        context.moveTo(points[0].x, points[0].y);
                        for (var t = 0; t <= slideVal; t += 0.1) {
                            context.lineTo(Math.pow(1 - t, 2) * points[0].x + 2 * (1 - t) * t * points[1].x + Math.pow(t, 2) * points[2].x, Math.pow(1 - t, 2) * points[0].y + 2 * (1 - t) * t * points[1].y + Math.pow(t, 2) * points[2].y);
                        }

                        // Stroke path
                        context.stroke();
                    }

                    function erase(canvasId) {

                        var canvas = document.getElementById(canvasId);
                        var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
                        context.beginPath();
                        context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                        canvas.width = canvas.width;

                    }

                    function drawSlopeCurve1(canId) {
                        var canvas = document.getElementById(canId);
                        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

                        context.beginPath();
                        context.moveTo(16, 170);
                        context.lineTo(160, 72);
                        context.lineWidth = 0.6;
                        context.stroke();
                    }

                </script>

            </html>
```

Comment: You are not calling the `drawSlopeCurve1` function on the slider movement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your **slide1** input like this:

```
<input id="slide1" type="range" min="0" max="100" step="1" value="0" onchange="counterSliderNew('slide1', '100'); drawSlopeCurve1('slide1',100);" />
```

Update your **drawSlopeCurve1** function like this:

```
function drawSlopeCurve1(sID,maxValue) {
    erase('canvasTwo');                        

    var canId = 'canvasTwo';
    var slideVal = parseInt(document.getElementById(sID).value);                        
    var canvas = document.getElementById(canId);
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    //line end points
    x1 = 16; y1 = 170;
    x2 = 160; y2 = 72;

    //get slope (rise over run)
    var m = (y2-y1)/(x2-x1);
    //get y-intercept
    var b = y1 - (m * x1);
    //get distance between the two points
    var distance = Math.sqrt((x2-x1)*(x2-x1) + (y2-y1)*(y2-y1));
    //get new x and y values
    var x = x1 + parseInt(distance/maxValue * slideVal);
    var y = parseInt(m * x + b);

    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(x1, y1);
    context.lineTo(x, y);
    context.lineWidth = 0.6;
    context.stroke();
}
```

(you can put in any values you want for line end points x1,y1 and x2,y2)
[**LIVE EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/L2pmB/)

Comment: Many thanks for answer. Can you tell me the formula for increment the lines also I have to draw one more line with different points that is this time it is context.moveTo(16, 170); and context.lineTo(200, 80);

Comment: I updated the code above (both input line and the drawSlopeCurve1 function). Now you can enter the line end points you want. The start point is x1,y1 and the end point is x2,y2. To understand what is going on here, research "slope of a line y=mx+b" and "distance between 2 points". A tricky part of the code that may be hard to understand is the "distance/maxValue * slideVal". This is the amount of distance to increase the new x value on each slider change. I also updated the jsFiddle live example. Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi any idea how to draw bezier curve on the movement of slider? I manage to get the code for quadratic curve but could not get any code for bezier curve. Also I am trying to move an object on the curve I am drawing. Thanks